# Express API not retrieving rows from table in postgres database on neon

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, neon.tech

So I've made a simple express api that it supposed to retrieve all rows from a table in my postgressql database which i've made on neon.
It shows that it has been connected and the http request is also going through so I don't really know where the issue lies.

I get 'undefined' in my console.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const postgres = require("postgres");
require("dotenv").config();

const sql = postgres(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { ssl: "require" });

async function getPostgresVersion() {
  try {
    const response = await sql`select version()`;
    console.log("PostgreSQL Version:", response[0].version);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching PostgreSQL version:", error);
  }
}

getPostgresVersion();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/forums", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { rows } = await sql`SELECT * FROM forums`;
    if (rows) {
      console.log("Fetched rows:", rows);
      res.json(rows);
    } else {
      console.error("No rows retrieved from the database.");
      res.status(404).json({ message: "No data found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Database Error:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at ${port}`);
});
```

I've tried the query on the neon editor and it works. I've also tried adding

```
rows.forEach((row) => {
        console.log("Row Data:", row);
      });
```

it does not work